# Image upload using Laravel 5.4 Intervention Image 2.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to upload an image and resize it using Intervention Image 2.x. But I get an error called `Image source not readable`.

Is there a way to debug this error.

[image]

I'm using the following code shown in the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads).

```
Image::make($request->file('productImage'))->resize(800, 500)->save('foo.jpg');
```

And my view part responsible for file upload is,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Image</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="file" id="productImage" name="productImage">
         <p class="help-block">Upload product Image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are lots of resources for older version of Laravel, but it's hard to find resources for Laravel 5.4

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: No, Do I need to include that?

Comment: Yes. This allows files to be included in the data.

Comment: Thanks! I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your form have enctype="multipart/form-data", if you use laravel collective

{{ Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put', 'files' => true]) }}

Comment: I'm not using Laravel form helper library. So I did add the enctype="multipart/form-data" tag to form element. Your answer is right. Thanks!